# FastAPI - Field required, missing value

Tags: python, html, forms, fastapi

I receive the error below, when I deploy my app to Heroku:

```json
{
   "detail": [
      {
         "loc": [
               "body",
               "id"
         ],
         "msg": "field required",
         "type": "value_error.missing"
      }
   ]
}
```

and log in the console:

`22-03-05T19:45:12.863425+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=wallet-reputation.herokuapp.com request_id=51780a1f-491a-4dd6-a8c0-164b41745405 fwd="95.175.20.47" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=422 bytes=248 protocol=http`

This is my Fastapi app:

```py
@app.get("/")
def index(request: Request, id: str = Form(...)):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("main_page.html", context={"request": request})
```

That's how my HTML file looks like:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Main Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="get">
      <center>
      <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
        <label for="walletAdress">Natluk Coin Reputation Wallet</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="walletAdress" aria-describedby="walletlHelp"
               placeholder="Wallet address" style="text-align: center" name="id">
      </div>
      </center>
      <center>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" role="button"
           href="https://wallet-reputation.herokuapp.com/wallet/{{ id }}">Check Wallet</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" role="button"
           href="https://wallet-reputation.herokuapp.com/wallet/run/{{ id }}">Create Wallet</a>
      </center>
</html>
```

So the logic is that, when I access my `"/"` endpoint I post the string into form, and then I click one of the buttons, which starts running the endpoint with variable from form.

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure if I get what you're asking me. Request parameter is necessary (info from FastAPI documentation). When I set default value in Form like -> Form(default="smth") it works, but I can change this value when I type string to my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Below is an example of how to submit a value through form, and how your endpoint should look like:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status, Form
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def event_create_form(request: Request):
    html_content = """
    <html>
       <body>
          <form method="POST" action="/submit">
             <input type="text" name="id">
             <input type="submit" value="Create Event">
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=html_content, status_code=200)
    
@app.post('/submit')
async def event_create(id: int = Form(...)):
    return {"id": id}
```

---

### Original answer

You are submitting `id` as [`path`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/) parameter, but your endpoint expects it to be a body ([`Form`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/)) parameter. Thus, you should change your endpoint as shown below, so that `id` is expected as path parameter:

```
@app.get("/{id}")
def index(request: Request, id: str):
    ...
```

Comment: Not exactly. In simple, what I want to accomplish. Open home page "/" where I have form to put their string which will be pass to one of two buttons below form. Thus, buttons have href value which is enriched with string from form "https://wallet-reputation.herokuapp.com/wallet/{{ id }}"